# GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon: Unable to autolaunch when setuid

Tags: terminal, linux-mint, gtk

I am encountering a strange error whenever I run certain commands, for example, `sudo apt-get install ______` and I receive the following error:

> (process:28847): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the
>   D-BUS daemon: Unable to autolaunch when setuid
>
> (process:28847): Gtk-WARNING **: This process is currently running
>   setuid or setgid. This is not a supported use of GTK+. You must create
>   a helper program instead. For further details, see:
>
> ```
> http://www.gtk.org/setuid.html
> ```
>
> Refusing to initialize GTK+.

Which is odd, because I can still go ahead and enter my password and everything proceeds, I'm just wondering why I am receiving this message.

I am using linux-mint xfce 15 Olivia

Comment: You sure that is with `sudo apt-get`? It shouldn't be like that. What is the output of `type sudo` and `type apt-get`.

Comment: @Braiam - `type sudo` returns `sudo is hashed (/usr/bin/sudo)` and `type apt-get` returns `apt-get is /usr/bin/apt-get`. I have a feeling it is due to `sudo` as simply doing `sudo username` also causes the same error to appear.